# How to redirect to a view controller based on the status of location services in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm using the following code to check to see if the user's location services for the app have changed. If they change they should view a different view controller. It really only needs to run each time the app launches and then redirect based on the `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` status

the problem with my  code is that everytime the location updates the segue is ran.

thanks for any help

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
//locLabel.text = [location description];

NSLog(@"auth status is %u", [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]);

if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueOffersGPS" sender: self];

} else {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueOffersNoGPS" sender: self];

}
```

Comment: After first time, stop updating location !!!

Comment: @Maulik thanks :) how would I go about doing that though? Just run once and then only again when the app relaunches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop updating location then write below code

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
     [self.locationManger stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```